# How to embed a range from GSHEETS in GDOCS with google-apps-scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to have the same result as copying from GSHEETS and paste in GDOCS. That means that the link of the embedded object needs to stay, that I will be asked to update if the source changes.

But I would like to do it with Google apps scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to inform you that as right now there seems to be **no way** of actually doing this through [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), neither the [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api).

You could try to file this as a Feature Request and try to getting it implemented, take a look at [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).