# How to copy certain range in gsheet and paste them in gdocs template using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

My gsheet has some formatted texts and a table. I need to copy this whole content and paste it into a gdoc template which I have created blank content except for header (contain logo, images & hyperlinks) and footer (business address) and then convert the fulfilled gdoc to pdf.

Initially I referred to [How to embed a range from GSHEETS in GDOCS with google-apps-scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492376/how-to-embed-a-range-from-gsheets-in-gdocs-with-google-apps-scripts) but that one was embedding the link and objects and from the answer I knew already it is not possible for now, but I wish pasting the copied content while retaining all the formats and tables is still possible.

I tried the code below. No error but all pasted as plain text only because I only know replaceText command. Anyone can correct my code, please?

```
function sheetTodocTopdf() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = sheet.getSheetByName("Import");
 
  //file is the gdoc template file
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('13mFHFOQw8JTXzXLlgmlIRFBQA2_LL9uEZSOS2BumqeQ'); 
  
  //duplicate the template file in the same folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Z9UWlwSyeklKUHOlCevMyKq56K1QwApC')
  var copy = file.makeCopy("Report", folder); 
  
  //Open the duplicated gdoc
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var lastRow = source.getLastRow();
  
  var srcRange = source.getRange("A1:G57").getValues();
      
  //Replacing the text in the gdoc with the copied range of gsheet
  doc.replaceText('{content}', srcRange); 
  
  doc.saveAndClose();

  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");
  var pdf = doc.setName("Report.pdf");

  folder.createFile(pdf); 
};
```

Thanks.
DZ

Comment: If you want a PDF at the end I'd suggest to do everything within Spreadsheet. You could try to add your header with a logo and hyperlinks, etc on sheet and save the sheet as PDF.

Comment: You can paste a 2d array as a table into GDoc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table It's not a big deal. But keep formatting of the cells it can be a hard task. It depends on how exactly your table looks like.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, I did that before but it doesn't work for footer. That's why I came to think of this alternative. GAS doesn't have param or syntax or command to pass custom footer we set in the gsheet when producing the pdf. but everything just nice with gdocs.

Comment: And of course, if your data happens to have always the same number of rows and columns, you can make a doc template with a dummy table and replace its data cell by cell rather than to replace the whole table at once. This way cells formatting will stay intact. Probably you can add new rows to the dummy table (and keep the formatting from previous rows) before fill its cells with new data.

Comment: I thot about creating invisible table but I haven't tried it coz it sounds like so much hassles. So, with all your workaround suggestions, does this mean that in short, there's no way to do it with simple GAS syntax/command/param?

Comment: The table in the template is originally has 70 rows. the data inside each row will depend on input from the user. so, if user only entered input for 30 rows, there should be also GAS to delete the blank rows before convert it to pdf. So, the final length of the doc will vary from one record to another. That's why I need to have the header and footer to stay intact

Comment: Not that I'm a full fledged certified expert in GAS... But, yeah, I think the task has no simply solution. You have to use workarounds or to dive into murky coding — you can make 2d array with data and 2d array with text attributes (from sheet) and try to apply the attributes on every cell in doc. Something like this. But if every your row has the same formatting the code could be not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have such dummy table (with correct formatting) in Google Docs:

[image]

You can add rows to the table from Spreadsheet this way:

```
function add_rows_to_existed_table() {

  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_ID);
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[0];
  const bottom_row = table.getRow(2); // get the bottom row
  table.removeRow(2);                 // remove the bottom row
  const row = table.getRow(1);        // get second row

  for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {           // append second row five times
    let new_row = row.copy();
    table.appendTableRow(new_row);
  }
  
  table.appendTableRow(bottom_row);   // restore the bottom row
}
```

[image]

After that you can change contents of every cell in the table with text from your Spreadsheet table.

**Update**

So the more of less full implementation would be something like this:

```
const doc_ID = "###";

function main() {
  const doc  = DocumentApp.openById(doc_ID);
  const data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  add_rows_to_template_table(data, doc);
  replace_data_in_table(data, doc);
}

function add_rows_to_template_table(data, doc) {

  const body  = doc.getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[0];
  const bottom_row = table.getRow(2);  // get the bottom row
  table.removeRow(2);                  // remove the bottom row
  const row = table.getRow(1);         // get second row

  for (let i=1; i<data.length; i++) {  // append the second row several times
    let new_row = row.copy();
    table.appendTableRow(new_row);
  }
  
  table.appendTableRow(bottom_row);    // restore the bottom row
 
}

function replace_data_in_table(data, doc) {

  const body  = doc.getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[0];

  for (let row_index=0; row_index<data.length; row_index++) {
    let row = table.getRow(row_index+1); // skip a table header
    for (let cell_index=0; cell_index<data[0].length; cell_index++) {
      let cell = row.getCell(cell_index);
      // get attributes from a first character of a first paragraph in the cell
      let font_attributes = cell.getChild(0).getChild(0).asText().getAttributes();
      cell.setText(data[row_index][cell_index]);
      // apply the attributes to a first paragraph
      cell.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAttributes(font_attributes);
    }
  }

}
```

It takes the data from my Spreadsheet:

[image]

Takes my Doc template:

[image]

And fills the table in the template with the data (keep formatting):

[image]

The solution works but I believe it can be improved.

Comment: am still very new to GAS on gdocs. Will take sometime to try this one out. Shall update the soonest possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more full variant of the script.

Comment: The header and footer in my case here are not for the table actually. The header and footer are supposed to be for the gdocs, like a letterhead, where the logo is always gonna stay put at the top and the address or some text stay put at the bottom regardless how much content we have in that A4 size page.

Comment: And the data from gsheet is actually from gform GUI. So, the data input structure is in horizontal mode because 1 user's input = 1 row of values in sheet. while the output in the table in the gdocs shall be in vertical mode.  I use replaceText to change the values extracted in sheet to the docs. That's why I need to delete the blank rows after finished iteration.

Comment: Just a hint: It's always a good idea to show how your input and desired output should look like. It doesn't make sense to me to try to guess what else you have in mind.

Comment: Ok. Will update with some screenshots in the question column.

Comment: @dell  you should accept this answer as it addresses your question perfectly. The details about implementation, i.e. getting the formatting exactly right for your needs should have been clarified in the original question. If you are struggling with it still, I suggest accepting this answer and then asking a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot accept it as answer because the solution is not addressing my question. I have explained the header and the footer but the solution offered here is not addressing my needs. I clicked the up arrow because it does give a solution but it's just not to my question.